# make entire table cell trigger related checkbox

Tags: php, html

I have several checkboxes in php which are contained in a table:

```
<table>   
   <tr>
        <td>
            <input style='vertical-align:middle' type='checkbox' class='geomsize' name='frnd[]' value='$ScndryUid' id='$ScndryUid' />
         </td>   
   </tr> 
</table>
```

There is a checkbox in each table cell.

I am trying to make the entire table cell clickable.

I think that a td onclick event could work but no luck until now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the `<input>` inside a `<label>` with `width: 100%`:

**html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label><input type='checkbox' /></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
td { width: 300px; }
label { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }
```

**example** http://jsfiddle.net/tNKmM/1/

Comment: I wanted to recommend this method, but I believe you will run into issues doing this.  Something is nagging at me that I tried this in the past but it caused issues, but I can't recall the details and if it was a checkbox or some other type of input.

Comment: @jmbertucci One scenario is SemanticUI doesn't support having a label wrapping an input field, which I am very disappointed about because wrapping a label avoids having to add all the "for" and "ID"'s. I can imagine other frameworks might forget to handle both wrapping and sibling layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jQuery solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/c9Phn/6/

I wanted to recommend elclanrs solution, but I feel like I ran into an issue with wrapping the label around the item that it is pointing to.  It could have been a different but similar situation, I ran into but I can't recall the details right now.

I think elclanrs is a more elegant solution so try that, but if you have issues, the jQuery fallback is above.

Good luck!

Cheers!